# CSS3 textbox horizontal alignment, spacing a curvature

Tags: html, css

I have in the following image a button, 3 text boxes and another button.

[image]

I have been trying for a few hours to arrange it how I'd like and now my brain is fried.

I would prefer it like this:

[image]

Sorry for the poor drawing I did it in Paint.

Here is the HTML for each of the boxes:

```
<div class="keywords">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Keywords 1" type="text">
</div>

<div class="select-location">
 <input class="main-category" placeholder="Keywords 2" type="text">
</div>

<div class="select-location">
 <input class="main-category" placeholder="Keywords 3" type="text">
</div>
```

I understand Keywords 2 and 3 share the same class at the moment, I was doing this purely to get them aligned their current way.

Here is the CSS for Keywords and Select Location:

```
.keywords {
  float: left;
  width: 31%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.select-location {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 40px;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

I have spent quite a while trying to do this, however I have got myself into a muddle and can't figure it out.

Comment: Just to check if you know that you can set rounded corner on each of the 4 corners individually, i.e. `border-top-left-radius: 10px;`

Comment: Yeah I already knew that, thanks though. Whenever I add that into the CSS it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

**CSS**

```
.keywords {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 40px;
}


.wrapper{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #202020;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.select-location {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;

}

input{
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
      height: 40px;
    border:none;

}

button{
    display: block;
    width: 5%;
    height: 42px;
    border: none;   
    border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
    float:left;
}

button.firstb{
    float:left;
    border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
}
```

> Note: If you want to override existing classes just use `!important`

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/a3L6pqLg/5/)**